# I tried to send eth from Metamask (in balancer) but transfer is looking failed but I loss my eth(90$ around) What I should do?

Tags: metamask, cpp-ethereum, failed-transaction

I tried to send eth from Metamask but transfer is looking failed but I loss my eth(90$ around) What I should do?

Comment: You should include a link to the transaction that failed (etherscan.io)

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x389d0b4ec44c8b4f95344c9571fee81b167d315e505dcb80f77e829d638db0d4

Comment: The 90$ are transactions fees and sadly can not be recovered..

Comment: yes, you didn't get the tokens because the tx is reverted but sadly that is not how it works for the fees and the user experience is still very bad. the miners got your transaction and mined it for your given fee, but you are responsible for what inside the transaction (like value to transfer and other stuff are correct) and not them. sorry for your that and hope you learned something new for 90$ :)

Answer (score 1):

from balancer contract

```
require(poolAmountOut >= minPoolAmountOut, "ERR_LIMIT_OUT");
```

it seems like the quantity of assets going out is less than the minimum required quantity.

you can see how it is calculated here: https://github.com/balancer-labs/balancer-core/blob/master/contracts/BPool.sol#L562